# When does the cq:LiveSync property gets created?

Tags: aem, aem-6

Am not facing any issue but asking for general understanding.

When does the mixinType cq:LiveSync gets created?

One my AEM site, MSM works fine and ALL live copy pages are set with cq:LiveRelationship mixinType as expected. 
Some pages have cq:PropertyLiveSyncCancelled and corresponding cq:propertyInheritanceCancelled property tells which all properties are cancelled. Its clear cq:PropertyLiveSyncCancelled is set when someone cancels inheritance against a property.

But few pages have [cq:LiveSync](https://helpx.adobe.com/ca/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/custom-nodetypes.html#cqLiveSyncConfig) property set and many dont. Trying to understand what action sets this property? and what impact it has on MSM?